# Eclipse Gradle The requested build type 'java-library' is not supported

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle

I want to create an exe out of my java project which uses a lot of images as assets. I tried the export function of Eclipse but it didnt work exactly. So ı decided to try gradle. I installed gradle as instructed, my Eclipse has the gradle plugin too but whenever I try to create a Gradle porject, ı get the following error in console:

---

> Task :wrapper
> Task :init FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':init'.

> The requested build type 'java-library' is not supported. Supported types:
> - 'basic'
> - 'cpp-application'
> - 'cpp-library'
> - 'groovy-applıcatıon'
> - 'groovy-gradle-plugin'
> - 'groovy-lıbrary'
> - 'java-applıcatıon'
> - 'java-gradle-plugin'
> - 'java-lıbrary'
> - 'kotlin-applıcatıon'
> - 'kotlin-gradle-plugin'
> - 'kotlin-lıbrary'
> - 'pom'
> - 'scala-applıcatıon'
> - 'scala-lıbrary'
> - 'swift-application'
> - 'swift-library'

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

BUİLD FAILED in 237ms
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed

---

I dont know what to do, I am so new to creating jars and exe files.

Comment: i'm confused, you're trying to create an exe file, right ? so what does this have to do with android ?

Comment: Well nothing. Im trying to create a jar file using gradle adn then create an exe using that jar file with launch4j. Am I terribly mistaken?